# Alternative of 'disable/disabled' in software contexts

Tags: word-choice

In light of movement to "clean" up language used in software like "master/slave" and "white/black" lists.

What could be instead of "to disable"a software or feature, or when a software or feature is "disabled"?

The option that seems as close and flexible is "to deactivate" and "deactivated". Others like "turn off" don't have the an adjective for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with *deactivated* is that it's really a past-tense verb, and not a regular adjective. It can be used adjectivally (and often is), but you might want to come up with a word that has normal verb and adjective counterparts.

Something close, but more versatile, is this pairing (links are to Merriam-Webster):

- active / activate
- [inactive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inactive) / [inactivate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inactivate)

Of course, if you don't mind mixing the base words, you could use *inactive* for the adjective, but keep *deactivate* as the verb.

Comment: I like your last suggestion, as "inactivate" sounds strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

How about the pairing

enable <-> disenable

> Definition of disenable : DISQUALIFY, INCAPACITATE
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disenable

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! That was a an alternative that I also found shortly after I posted the question, but it did sound weird to me and it seems it was more used in the early 18th century according to the trends section of [collinsdictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/disenable) on it